# Power supply for 3x 18650 in series

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging

I want to charge 3x18650 batteries in series and for that, I want to use something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bluelover-Lithium-Battery-Charger-Protection/dp/B07688W1XG/) to have a balanced charge.

Which power supply should I use to charge the system? It's hard to find a 12.6V power supply. Will a 12V supply work? And a 15V supply?

Comment: Read the spec of your balance charger board, and it should tell you what voltage it requires. If it doesn't, buy one that does.

Answer (score 1):

That is only the BMS. It is not a charger. You must not use a power supply, as it does not know how to charge a battery. That might end up quickly in explosions and flames. What you need a is a battery charger for 3 cells.

Comment: Yes, I know that is only the BMS. That's why I'm looking for a power supply to connect to it. I want to charge with a simple AC/DC supply, like [this](https://www.amazon.es/TAIFU-UE22F5000AW-Alimentaci%C3%B3n-BN64-02326A-00-PSBN64-02326A-00/dp/B076BC5PJV/ref=pd_sbs_147_4/260-2216510-6160923?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B076BC5PJV&pd_rd_r=6bfdb85b-74fd-494a-acd1-904c01e4d702&pd_rd_w=PTGk4&pd_rd_wg=5fTDC&pf_rd_p=8e0d0316-fa0d-4a75-b68c-17be1e5e1b5a&pf_rd_r=K1X4591R3G30RFPCH0AF&psc=1&refRID=K1X4591R3G30RFPCH0AF).

Comment: @Miguel You're not looking for a power supply to connect to it, espacially not that 14 V thing you've linked, you're looking for a 3S lithium cell charger.

Comment: I don't want a 3S lithium cell charger for other reasons. Why can't I use that a power supply like the one I linked?

Comment: So you don't know the difference between a battery charger and a simple power supply? A simple power supply simply gives out power. It does not how to charge batteries. A charger knows how to charge batteries safely so that they don't explode. Never ever connect a simple power supply to batteries directly, you need charging circuitry between a simple power supply and the battery. You especially must use a 3S lithium cell charger, because, you are charging 3S lithium cells.